# Flexible Height Rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

In one of my projects, I created a structure similar to the one below for user reviews. My point is this: each review may vary in length from the next. And this means that the elements in each row can have different lengths. I want there to be 3 divs in each row, and I want the other divs to start just below the div in the top row. So my goal here is to create irregular rows. But I couldn't achieve this. How can I do that? (You can look at the image below.)

Edit: Code snippet added upon request. Link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/yw2VoqpTBi

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4 min-h-fit ">
      <div className="h-fit grid gap-8 p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta
        consectetur eos commodi maiores a laudantium provident dignissimos,
        quo cupiditate sapiente delectus laborum facere temporibus quos enim
        incidunt perspiciatis natus saepe expedita praesentium libero dicta
        nisi. Cupiditate repudiandae minima ipsum doloremque, ab molestias
        nemo ea perferendis hic. Eaque architecto hic repellendus.
      </div>
      <div className="h-fit grid gap-8 p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis
        voluptate omnis pariatur ullam eos reiciendis sed reprehenderit
        quisquam earum? Impedit vel blanditiis laudantium quos repellat
        asperiores voluptas, libero consectetur mollitia sint. Fugit eius
        dicta obcaecati facilis alias cum praesentium, ipsa veniam similique
        earum eaque dignissimos velit odit ipsam omnis facere modi beatae id
        voluptatum non. Quasi in accusantium optio obcaecati maxime
        pariatur, atque doloribus est? Quo, harum? Commodi ipsum a debitis
        cupiditate nam fuga consequatur harum eius dicta temporibus
        inventore unde obcaecati dolorem, officia perspiciatis voluptas enim
        quisquam nostrum tempore, beatae vel dolore minus. Vitae quaerat
        repellat deserunt iste temporibus expedita. Velit numquam officia
        nulla, sint corporis ab voluptatum blanditiis veritatis maxime, cum
        quas adipisci veniam corrupti? Eum totam quam vitae aperiam ratione,
        accusantium deserunt exercitationem culpa libero odit provident
        quaerat veniam voluptas, tempore eos animi ab. Autem, illo. Ea,
        maxime omnis. Repellendus nam debitis commodi dignissimos rerum
        beatae? Impedit?
      </div>
      <div className="h-fit grid gap-8 p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat
        aperiam, dolorem obcaecati atque praesentium nemo velit quae nihil
        voluptates id modi nam inventore itaque excepturi in saepe possimus
        magni quibusdam?
      </div>
      <div className="h-fit grid gap-8 p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus
        accusantium atque sit a quo eum, fuga inventore quisquam
        consequuntur necessitatibus velit possimus ducimus voluptatum vitae!
        Eaque unde, odio animi dolorem, architecto quas incidunt sint culpa
        optio commodi provident, dicta perspiciatis officia! Sunt laborum
        rem cumque placeat animi accusamus unde eveniet.
      </div>
      <div className="h-fit grid gap-8 p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur
        eum expedita alias consequuntur laudantium a tempore voluptatem
        ipsum? Voluptates harum magni eius non fugiat! Sunt perferendis nam
        odit eligendi minus. Accusantium ullam illum, reiciendis culpa ipsa
        excepturi quae voluptates velit vitae iste commodi exercitationem
        laborum praesentium error voluptatem repudiandae ut iusto voluptas,
        sed ducimus doloremque laboriosam sapiente! Vel, et nam corporis
        voluptas soluta harum quidem quisquam tempora dolore aspernatur
        ipsam?
      </div>
      <div className="h-fit grid gap-8 p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur
        eum expedita alias consequuntur laudantium a tempore voluptatem
        ipsum? Voluptates harum magni eius non fugiat! Sunt perferendis nam
        odit eligendi minus. Accusantium ullam illum, reiciendis culpa ipsa
        excepturi.
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Image of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ9F2.png)

Comment: @NarenMurali Hi Naren. I added a working code link upon your request. You can check it out here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/yw2VoqpTBi .  Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

The layout which you want to achieve is somewhat similar to *[Masonry layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Masonry_layout)*. You can use the `flex` utility and `space-x / space-y` to create columns manually and achieve the layout. Something like:

```html
<div class="flex min-h-fit space-x-4">
  <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3">
    <!-- First column -->
    <div class="h-fit p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500 mb-4">
      <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
    <div class="h-fit p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500 mb-4">
      <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3">
    <!-- Second column -->
    <div class="h-fit p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500 mb-4">
      <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
    <div class="h-fit p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500 mb-4">
      <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3">
    <!-- Third column -->
    <div class="h-fit p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500 mb-4">
      <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
    <div class="h-fit p-6 border rounded-lg bg-red-500 mb-4">
      <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/CNfqj2eyLh)